# i want to join table 1 into table2

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to ask MySQL table details from1 table to another
like:

Table 1:

```
id   name   phone
1    john   5645645644
2    harry  454654564
3    jolly  4654564
```

Table 2:

```
id   color   car
1     blue   swift
2     black   alto
3     red     sx4
```

I want the result in MySQL table 2: through php code

output inside the table2

Table 2:

```
id  name        phone           color     car   
1    john       5645645644      blue      swift
2    harry      454654564       black     alto
3    jolly      4654564         red       sx4
```

like this ouput above.

Comment: We are not a homework service for you

Comment: are these two ids from `table1` and `table2` related in anyway? Foreign key ? Or you can join using id's as join criteria.

Comment: Yeah! Go for it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SELECT Table1.id, Table1.name,Table1.phone,Table2.color, Table2.car 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id=Table2.id;

Comment: @shibinJOHN: if my answer is working for you then please accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: @Dharti Mirani ya its accepting very nice thankuu so much I already message u thankyou

Comment: @shibinJOHN This Question and *answer* site hinges upon _working_ answers being accepted.  Please accept this answer if it is working for you!